# TextInput react native component rendering on web but not on Expo Go with Expo and React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, textinput, input-field

I'm using React Native and Expo to create an android app with text fields. When I test on a web server, everything works, but not on Expo Go. Text components are in red and TextInput in blue.

Nothing in the debug DevTools of Expo Go (by pressing j).

package.json/dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
    "@expo/webpack-config": "^18.0.1",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.18.2",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.7",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.6.2",
    "expo": "~48.0.18",
    "expo-dev-client": "~2.2.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.8",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.10",
    "sass": "^1.63.3"
  },
```

CharacterScreen.js

```
import { useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

import { TextField } from '../UI';
import { app } from '../../utils/stylesheet';
import { DataContext } from '../../utils/DataContext';


function CharacterScreen() {
    const { data, setData } = useContext(DataContext)

    const onLastNameChange = text => setData({ ...data, char: { ...data.char, lastName: text }})
    const onNameChange = text => setData({ ...data, char: { ...data.char, name: text }})
    const onBreedChange = text => setData({ ...data, char: { ...data.char, breed: text }})
    const onClasseChange = text => setData({ ...data, char: { ...data.char, classe: text }})
    const onCareerChange = text => setData({ ...data, char: { ...data.char, career: text }})
    const onLevelChange = text => setData({ ...data, char: { ...data.char, level: text }})
    const onCareerPathChange = text => setData({ ...data, char: { ...data.char, careerPath: text }})
    const onStatusChange = text => setData({ ...data, char: { ...data.char, status: text }})
    const onAgeChange = text => setData({ ...data, char: { ...data.char, age: text }})
    const onHeightChange = text => setData({ ...data, char: { ...data.char, height: text }})
    const onHairChange = text => setData({ ...data, char: { ...data.char, hair: text }})
    const onEyesChange = text => setData({ ...data, char: { ...data.char, eyes: text }})
    const onSTAmbChange = text => setData({ ...data, char: { ...data.char, sTAmb: text }})
    const onLTAmbChange = text => setData({ ...data, char: { ...data.char, lTAmb: text }})


    return (
        <View style={app.screen}>
            <Text style={app.title}>Informations générales</Text>
            {
                data ? (<>
                    <TextField text='Prénom' value={data.char.lastName} update={onLastNameChange} />
                    <TextField text='Nom' value={data.char.name} update={onNameChange} />
                    <TextField text='Race' value={data.char.breed} update={onBreedChange} />
                    <TextField text='Classe' value={data.char.classe} update={onClasseChange} />
                    <TextField text='Carrière' value={data.char.career} update={onCareerChange} />
                    <TextField text='Echelon' value={data.char.level} update={onLevelChange} />
                    {/* <TextField text='Schéma de carrière value={data.char.careerPath} update={onCareerPathChange} /> */}
                    <TextField text='Statut' value={data.char.status} update={onStatusChange} />
                    <TextField text='Age' value={data.char.age} update={onAgeChange} />
                    <TextField text='Taille' value={data.char.height} update={onHeightChange} />
                    <TextField text='Cheveux' value={data.char.hair} update={onHairChange} />
                    <TextField text='Yeux' value={data.char.eyes} update={onEyesChange} />


                    <TextField text='A court terme' value={data.char.sTAmb} update={onSTAmbChange} />
                    <TextField text='A long terme' value={data.char.lTAmb} update={onLTAmbChange} />

                </>) : null
            }
        </View>
    );
}

export default CharacterScreen;
```

UI.js/TextField *a custom functional component that I've made*

```
export function TextField({ text, value, update }) {
    return (
        <Text style={textField.text}>{text} : <TextInput style={textField.style} value={value} onChangeText={update} placeHolder='...' /></Text>
    )
}
```

stylesheet.js/textField

```
export const textField = StyleSheet.create({
    style: {
        fontSize: 17,
        color: 'black',
        backgroundColor: 'blue'
    },
    text: {
        fontSize: 15,
        color: 'rgb(80, 80, 80)',
        backgroundColor: 'red'
    }
})
```

Nothing found on Internet about the problem ...
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem like you can have a `<TextInput/>` as the child of a `<Text>` component. Instead, move `<TextInput/>` out of the `<Text>` as such:

```js
export function TextField({text, value, update}) {
    return (
        <> {/* or <View style={...}> */}
            <Text style={textField.text}>{text} : </Text>
            <TextInput
                style={textField.style}
                value={value}
                onChangeText={update}
                placeHolder="..."
            />
        </> {/* or </View> */}
    );
}
```

Comment: Some changements required for styling but all is working, thanks a lot !!!!!!